# Bigquery SQL Standard Rank()

Tags: google-bigquery, sql

I had to convert all my legacy SQL to standard SQL.

I'm trying to join and rank() after I switch it to standard SQL and I'm getting an error message:

> "Number of arguments does not match for analytic function RANK. Supported signature: RANK()"

Does this mean the function RANK() does not work in SQL Standard? Bigquery is highlighting "RANK(MILESTONE)" as the error.

Much help is appreciated.

```
    JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT 
            CASE WHEN MILESTONE NOT LIKE '%M0' THEN 'CWV' ELSE MILESTONE END MILESTONE
            , MAX((LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)) AS LAST_MODIFIED_DATE
            , RANK(MILESTONE) OVER (ORDER BY MILESTONE DESC) AS RANK2     ------------NEED FIXING
            FROM `XXXXX.com:dataservices.Finance.FINANCE_SF_PRODUCT_COST_SNAPSHOT` 
            WHERE LOCKED IS false
            AND (DATE(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) = (SELECT MAX(DATE(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)) 
            FROM `XXXXXX.com:dataservices.Finance.FINANCE_SF_PRODUCT_COST_SNAPSHOT`)
            OR MILESTONE LIKE 'M0')
            AND PMD_PRODUCT_STATUS NOT IN ('Canceled','End of Life','No Longer Shipping')
            AND (MILESTONE NOT LIKE '%Exit%' OR MILESTONE NOT LIKE '%M0' OR MILESTONE NOT LIKE '%WP%')
            AND MILESTONE <> '2021_Q2_M0' -- need to show new qtr after each 20th of the month (just increase the Q#+1)
            GROUP BY 1
            ORDER BY 2 DESC
        )
        WHERE RANK2 < 4                       ------------NEED FIXING
    ) MILE
ON PCS.MILESTONES = MILE.MILESTONE
```

Comment: Why the <sql-standards> tag? (The above query is not SQL standard compliant - in several ways.)

Answer (score 1):

rank() doesn't get any parameter in any databases.

so :

```
select ...
     , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MILESTONE DESC) AS RANK2 
...
```

and I assume you meant to order by the expression you are grouping by:

```
select ...
     , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN MILESTONE NOT LIKE '%M0' THEN 'CWV' ELSE MILESTONE END DESC) AS RANK2 
...
```

Comment: Much help is appreciated @eshirvana

`, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MILESTONE DESC) AS RANK2`


------------Window ORDER BY expression references column MILESTONE which is neither grouped nor aggregated. Is it tell me to group withing this line? I'm pretty new to this SQL

Comment: by milestone inside rank partitioning you mean  "milestone column from table or  this : `CASE WHEN MILESTONE NOT LIKE '%M0' THEN 'CWV' ELSE MILESTONE END`, I think if you meant by ranking by the expression you are grouping by , that works

Comment: i mean "milestone column from table"

i'm having CASE extract MILESTONE column with only "M0"

Comment: @QuicKick , that's why you are getting that error message , because ranking on that column make sense in that context of subquery , because you are grouping with something else

Comment: I meant doesn't make sense